# jquery .js loading long delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Using `jquery.load()` to replace the content of a div everything works great, however there is a major performance issue. The page loaded into the div contains some external JavaScript files and using `HttpWatch` I have observed the following:

```
0   0   GET (Cache) text/javascript <host>/js/file1.js
0   0   GET (Cache) text/javascript <host>/js/file2.js
0   0   GET (Cache) text/javascript <host>/js/file3.js
...
etc.
```

and a little further below (during the same `load()`):

```
571 129862  GET 200 text/javascript <host>/js/file1.js?_=1263399258240
569 26439   GET 200 text/javascript <host>/js/file2.js?_=1263399258365
572 14683   GET 200 text/javascript <host>/js/file3.js?_=1263399258396
...
etc.
```

The same scripts seem to be loaded again for some reason. Even worse, there appears to be a freeze in the browser just before the files are fetched again.

Can I prevent jQuery from loading the files again? This whole issue is causing around a 5-sec delay to my page. Also, what is the meaning of the `_=1263399258240`?

Comment: Can you post the code that loads the scripts?  The `_=1263399258xxx` appears to be a timestamp (current time in milliseconds since Jan 1 1970 I think) appended to the query in order to avoid caching.

Comment: The page is loaded with:
jQuery(div).load(targetPage, function(){callback()});

The timestamp is likely to be appended to avoid caching however I don't see any reason why it should not be cached in my case. I'd prefer to be able to turn this off and use the previously loaded.

Comment: Yes that's right. By adding the url query string `?<something random or unique>` to the url of a javascript file, the browser is forced to reload it, and the server will ignore the `?` and everything after, sending back just the javascript file. I would suggest looking at the jQuery docs to see whether there is an ajax option to "allow cache" or similar, which might prevent the url querystring from being sent. If there is such an option and it happens to be global, I'd suggest reverting it back to the default after you have sent the AJAX request.

Comment: Ok, so I discovered the jQuery docs can only get you half way there, so I trawled through the code as well (I'm actually doing similar things, so it wasn't really a problem to spend the time on it). I've included a couple of methods in my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has three different cache options. The default `null` allows caching for all requests *except* scripts and json requests, whilst `true` and `false` apply to all requests. As far as I can tell, you cannot provide an options argument in the `load()` method, so you need to change the global jQuery ajax options.

I've given different ways to do this below.

1. The first attempts to retain the previous global option after your request is complete (but does have its drawbacks).
2. The second disregards the default setting and just sets the option so that you *always* allow cache to be used for ajax results (if this is not an issue for you, **I'd recommend this one**, as it's the simplest, with no hidden pitfalls), and
3. the third example is if you want to allow caching of scripts, but not other ajax requests.

**Example 1:**

My first example shows how to do this if you want to revert back to normal settings after the load() request:

```
    //first store defaults (we may want to revert to them)
 1: var prevCacheVal = $.ajaxSettings.cache; 
    //then tell jQuery that you want ajax to use cache if possible
 2: $.ajaxSetup({cache: true}); 
    //then call the load method with a callback function 
 3: $(myDiv).load(myURL,function(){
      /* revert back to previous settings. Note that jQuery makes 
         a distinction between false and null (null means never
         cache scripts, false means never cache anything). so it's
         important that the triple-equals operators are used, to
         check for "false" and not just "falsey" */
 4:   if (prevCacheVal === false) $.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
 5:   else if (prevCacheVal !== true) $.ajaxSetup({cache: null});
      //else prev was true, so we need not change anything
 6: });
```

**Important Note** that in doing the above, you need to be careful you're only sending one request at a time, as storing and switching the "default" each time could lead to race conditions. If you need the above functionality *and* ability to send parallel requests, you'd be better off writing your own wrapper for the `jQuery.ajax()` method so you can pass in the `cache` option on a per-request basis. This would be similar to Andres' suggested approach below, but with the fixes I suggested to specify `cache: true` and to use `jQuery.html();` rather than `innerHTML`. However, it gets more complicated than that, because internally, `jQuery.html();` requests scripts using the global option, so you'd also need to override some of the internal functionality deep within function calls that `html();` makes - not something to be done lightheartedly, but certainly possible.

**Example 2:** (recommended for the original question asker)

Now, if you don't care about restoring defaults, and want cache to be on for *all* ajax requests, you can simply call `$.ajaxSetup({cache: true});` and call `load()` as you previously did:

```
 $.ajaxSetup({cache: true}); 
 $(myDiv).load(myURL);
```

**Example 3:**

And if you want the myURL to *not* be loaded from cache (let's say its dynamic), but *do* want to cache the scripts, you'll need to add a unique-ish/random query to myURL, such as:

```
 $.ajaxSetup({cache: true}); 
 $(myDiv).load(myURL + "?myuniquetime=" + Date.getTime()); 
 /* getTime() is milliseconds since 1970 - should be unique enough, 
    unless you are firing of many per second, in which case you could
    use Math.random() instead. Also note that if myURL already includes
    a URL querystring, you'd want to replace '?' with '&' */
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to this issue would be to do something:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="load1"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: "load1.html",
        success: function(data){
            $("#load1")[0].innerHTML = data;
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

load1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js1.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div>html 1</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will work, however A) he wants `cache: true` (guessing its just a typo), and B) it bypasses all the usual sanitisation stuff that jQuery's `.html()` method does, by using `.innerHTML`. Effectively, this is adding everything, including the `<html>` tags, `<body>` tags and other unnecessary stuff into a div.